# Remove all files that start with same prefix, but different filetype

Tags: bash, rm

How do I remove all files in a folder that start with the same prefix? For example:

I have files:

```
SVM1.txt
SVM2.csv
SVM3.mat
helloworld.txt
README.txt
```

I want to delete all the files that start with 'SVM'. Note that they start with the same prefix, but are of different filetype!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With wildcards, of course.

```
rm SVM*
```

Comment: Surely we can Goldberg it to at least `for i in $(seq 1 3); do rm SVM${i}*; done`. Where's the fun in doing it correctly and efficiently?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There is almost never only one way of doing something correctly in shell scripting.

Comment: I apologize, I presumed inclusion of "Goldberg" (as in Rube Goldberg) would have conveyed the appropriate level of sincerity in the comment...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I get the sarcasm, But there are still legitimate cases where `for i in SVM*; do rm "$i"; done` or [khadija's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25027302/3076724) are better than `rm SVM*`.

Comment: You are correct. There are many different ways to "skin a cat" and experience tells you witch is best suited for any one occasion. In another situation `declare -i n=1; while test "$n" -le 3 ; do rm SVM${n}*; ((n++)); done` might be appropriate as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Except that your two cases have no benefit over `rm SVM*`. The two I brought up do, i.e. handling large numbers of `SVM` files.

Comment: Thus the "Goldberg" -- are you sure you **get the sarcasm**? The comment was a **complement** to Ignacio, juxtaposed to other answers on the page :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the straightforward

```
rm SVM*
```

which might fail (command line too long) if there are many, many matching files, you can use

```
find . -prune -name 'SVM*' -exec rm {} +
```

which will repeatedly run `rm` on as many files at a time as possible until all matching files are deleted. `-prune` keeps `find` from descending into any subdirectories to find matching files.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where the files are,

ls | grep '^SVM.*' | xargs rm

Stop at grep ^SVM.* to double check that you have the right files to delete, then add the xargs rm.

Comment: At best this is inefficient (two processes to find and filter the files, plus one `rm` *per file*), at worst wrong (when a file name contains a newline).

Comment: So just for clarification, if rm SVM* is used, after the shell performs command line expansion does this mean that only one rm is being applied to all the files?

Comment: @khadija Yes, though I don't think what you are doing warrants -1. `rm SVM*` will fail on `ARG_MAX`, your syntax will fail on files with newlines, but neither case is present in the example.

Comment: @khadija Although you may want to quote `'^SVM.*'`